# Discord bot can't join voice channel in 13.1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const connection = await voice_channel.join();
```

Gives me the error:

```
voice_channel.join is not a function
```

I have `@discordjs/voice` installed and everything but it does not work in my code. Does anyone know how I fix this? The same is with my

```
voice_channel.leave();
```

which also just gives me the error that it's not a function. Can anyone provide a code example for how I fix this? And yes I have this in my code:

```
const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
```

Comment: What is not a function?
"which also just gives me the error that its not a function"

Comment: that voice_channel.join is not a function. not voice_channel.leave either

Comment: Can you log voice_channel? What is it defined as?

Comment: i console.log(voice_chanel) and get this: <ref *2> VoiceChannel {
  type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
  deleted: false,
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    id: '798920134411550720',
    name: 'Seelio',
    icon: 'd46b4d7bcf6c330a6494685f39f6b1be',
    features: [],
    commands: GuildApplicationCommandManager {
      permissions: [ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    members: GuildMemberManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    channels: GuildChannelManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    bans: GuildBanManager { guild: [Circular *1] }
    I cant send the whole log

Comment: Though you have @discordjs/voice installed, you will have to use the functions provided there. `VoiceChannel.join` and `VoiceChannel.leave` no longer exist.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how do i leave a voice channel? Do i use leaveVoiceChannel?

Answer (score 1):

In version 13 joining a voice channel has been changed. You can read all about it in the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin). To join a voice channel you must now use the `joinVoiceChannel()` command from `discordjs/voice`. It is used like this:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: channel.id,
  guildId: channel.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
})
```

The channel variable in this example is an instance of `BaseGuildVoiceChannel`.

To leave the channel just call `.disconnect()` or `.destroy()` on your `connection` object.